# Web Application that Displays Seperate Views for Different Monitors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, web, multiple-monitors

I'm researching a project that involves displaying different data on different monitors.  Essentially it is a like a game show app.  The idea is a teacher plugs his/her laptop into a projector and starts the application.  The projector displays the question with a countdown timer.  The laptop screen shows the question & countdown timer but also shows the answer to the question as well as a list of students so the teacher can select the one that got the answer right so it can keep score.

I think it would be fairly straightforward as a window forms application but I'd like to make it web-based so that we don't have to worry about the specs of the teachers' machines being compatible, distributing updates to the various teachers, etc.

It looks like Silverlight may be a possible solution based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267137/multiple-screens-monitors-with-silverlight), but I was wondering if there were any other options for this.  Also, since I'm in the research phase, I'm pretty flexible about looking at different options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get something working with ASP.Net by having two different pages, one for the laptop screen, the other for the projector, and have the two pages talk to the server via SignalR.

The teacher would need to manually move the pages to the right monitor, though.